# Using Google Apps Script how to only retrieve objects from ScriptDb which possess property/key

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to query ScriptDb to return only those objects which possess a specific property/key?

```
results = db.query({key: db.not(null)}); // always triggers error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."
results = db.query({key: db.not(undefined)}); // returns all objects in the database
```

and the reverse:

```
results = db.query({key: undefined}); 
results = db.query({key: null});         // both these cause an error on any of the ScriptDbResult methods "Your query object contains an invalid component."
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: results = db.query({key: db.anyValue()});

Comment: of course - missed that!

Comment: ScriptDB was deprecated. Related [How to replace the deprecated ScriptDb with Mongodb using URL Fetch service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24033530/1595451), [What alternative to ScriptDB I could use to store a big array of arrays? (without using external DB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652194/1595451)