# What alternative to ScriptDB I could use to store a big array of arrays? (without using external DB)

Tags: google-apps-script

I was a user of the deprecated ScriptDB. The use I made of ScriptDB was fairly simple: to store a certain amount of information contained on a panel options, this way:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();

function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
         var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
         var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
         if (thesesType != ''){
             var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
        arrayList.push(newArray);
        break;
         }
      }
   }
  arrayList.sort();
  var result = db.query({arrayName: 'savedArray'});
  if (result.hasNext()) {
    var savedArray = result.next();
    savedArray.arrayValue = arrayList;
    db.save(savedArray);
    }
  else {
    var record = db.save({arrayName: "savedArray", arrayValue:arrayList});
  }
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(550).setHeight(450);
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
                   .setId('panel');
    var label = app.createLabel("Choose the options").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
    app.add(label);
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
   }
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
   panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);
   mydoc.show(app);
}

function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) // if we find a match, return true
            return true;    }
    return false; // if we got here, there was no match, so return false
 }

function submit(e){
  var scriptDbObject = db.query({arrayName: "savedArray"});
  var result = scriptDbObject.next();
  var arrayList = result.arrayValue;
  db.remove(result);
  // continues...
 }
```

I thought I could simply replace the ScriptDB by userProperties (using JSON to turn the array into string). However, an error warns me that my piece of information is too large to be stored in userProperties.

I did not want to use external databases (parse or MongoDB), because I think it isn't necessary for my (simple) purpose.

So, what solution I could use as a replacement to ScriptDB?

Comment: How big is the property you're trying to store? GAS has a limit of 9kB/property and 500kB/property store. If it's under 500kB, maybe you can store your data in multiple properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store a string using the HtmlOutput Class.

```
 var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
 output.append('<p>Hello again, world.</p>');
 Logger.log(output.getContent());
```

[Google Documentation - HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)

There are methods to append, clear and get the content out of the HtmlOutput object.

OR

Maybe create a Blob:

[Google Documentation - Utilities Class - newBlob Method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte))

Then you can get the data out of the blob as a string.

[getDataAsString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString())

Then if you need to you can convert the string to an object if it's in the right JSON format.

Comment: All try to implement today the blob solution

Comment: I`m having trouble with the blob solution... :/

Comment: Maybe post what you've got so far to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're hitting the limits on the Properties service, I would recommend you look at an alternative external store, as you're manipulating a large amount of data, and any workaround given here is possibly going to be slower and less efficient then simply using a dedicated service.

Alternatively of course, you could look at making your data come under the limits for the properties service by splitting it up and using multiple properties etc.

One other alternative would be to use a Google Doc or Sheet to store the string. When you're required to pull the data again, you can simply access the sheet and get the string, but this might be slow depending on the size of the string. At a glance it looks like you're just pulling Data on the folders in your drive, so you could consider writing it to a sheet, which would allow you to even display the information in a user friendly way. Given your use of arrays already, you can write them to a sheet easily using [.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) if you convert them to a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce McPherson has done a lot of work on [abstracting databases](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/dbabstraction). Take a look at his cDbAbstraction library then you could easily chop and change which DB you use and compare performance. Maybe even create a cDbAbstraction library to use HTMLOutput (I like that idea Sandy, [Bruce does some funky stuff with parallel processes via HTMLService](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/htmlservice/parallel))